# SharePoint CAML Query - Chinese Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml

Trying to select from Library(Chinese Characters) getting -Object reference not set to an instance of an object - This working for English sites - Not sure how to convert?

```
    ClientContext context = new ClientContext(URL);

    context.Credentials = GetSharepointCredentials();

    Web web = context.Web;

    List pages = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Site Pages");                

    string dateQuery = string.Concat(@<View> +
       "<ViewFields>" +

          "<FieldRef Name='Created'/> +
          "<FieldRef Name='Title'/> +
          "<FieldRef Name='FileRef'/> +
          "<FieldRef Name=" + PAGECONTENT + /> +

       </ViewFields> 

          <Query> +
            <Where> +
              "<Geq>" +
               "<FieldRef Name='FirstPublishedDate' />" +
              "<Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-" + DIGEST_FREQUENCY + "'/></Value>" +
              "</Geq>" +
            "</Where>" +
             "<OrderBy>" +
               "<FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='True' />" +
             "</OrderBy>" +
        "</Query></View>");
    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();

    query.ViewXml = dateQuery;

    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection allArticles = pages.GetItems(query);

    context.Load(allArticles);

    context.ExecuteQuery(); ---> Error Here
```

Comment: are you using multilingual? Please share the relative url of both english and chinese site?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Chinese language site, the Site Pages library name should be Conver to "网站主页" as list name, see the code sample below, I tested without CAML Condition:

```
        using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/chines"))
        {
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(web, a => a.ServerRelativeUrl);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("网站页面");
            clientContext.Load(list);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();

            ListItemCollection listCol = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.Load(listCol);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (var item in listCol)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"]);
            }
        }
```